# Determine all the differentiable functions $f : [0, 1] → R$ satisfying the conditions $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$ and $|f'(x)| ≤ 1/2$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Tags: calculus

Determine all the differentiable functions $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow R$ satisfying the conditions
$f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$ and $|f'(x)| ≤ 1/2$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$.

I applied LMVT in the interval $(x,1)$ and arrived at a solution that $f(x)= \frac{(x+1)}{2}$ and then on applying LMVT in $(0,x)$ I could not conclude anything

Comment: Please format correctly. What have you tried?

Comment: What does the Mean Value Theorem tell you?

Comment: I applied LMVT in the interval (x,1) and arrived at a solution that f(x)=(x+1)/2 and then on applying LMVT in (0,x) I could not conclude anything

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: Just apply $LMVT$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: MVT would imply the derivative of such an $f$ would have value 1 somewhere.

Comment: @DavidMitra Then how should I go about it?

Comment: So, there are no such functions.

Comment: can anyone provide the proper solution, I am getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x)| = \left| \int_{0}^{x}f^{'}(t) \,dt \right| \le \int_0^{x} |f'(t)| \, dt \le \int_0^{x}\frac{1}{2} \,dt = \frac{x}{2}.$$ But $f(1) = 1$, so no such function.

Comment: Thanks a lot.